# clone disk with resume

Tags: linux, hard-drive, clone

I need to clone a disk. usually i've been doing this straightforward with dd. But in this case the disk i need to clone is an external USB-Disk that is 5TB large. So I'm guessing this will take somewhat between "way to long" and "an eternity".

Is there a cloning method that supports resuming (if something goes wrong, the PC crashes or I need to stop the process for some reason)?

The disk in question contains only one ext4 partition and is basically a data dump, so nothing complicated there.

Comment: `ddrescue` does it. Just shooting from the hip.

Comment: Do you need a complete disk image? What about file-based programs like rsync? Rsync doesn't support sessions / resuming, but can quickly skip over files previously sync'd.

Comment: `ddrescue`, yes; but not if "some reason" involves writing to the device being cloned.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `rsync` on the underlying file system, but you can also use it on the disk partition itself. From [this discussion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/48298/can-rsync-resume-after-being-interrupted) on Unix stackexchange it looks like the `--partial-dir` option could help you.

There are also options in `dd` that could help: `seek=N` and `skip=N`, while also using `append` mode.

Comment: Not sure I'd trust any disk image which was made in multiple steps. On my home PC, using Macrium Reflect, imaging 3 TB takes about 6 hours with verification turned on, so depending on system and HDD speed, 5TB should be done in less than 12 hours.